# Powershell Get Sync provisioning errors AzureAD

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I need to adapt a script that currently is using Msol-Service module with the AzureAD module. I have a script developed in Powershell that use Get-MsolDirSyncProvisioningError to check the sync errors in my tenant.

```
Get-MsolDirSyncProvisioningError -ErrorCategory PropertyConflict
```

I've searched in AzureAD cmdlets' documentation and i don't saw any cmdlet that do something.

Which is the same cmdlet in AzureAD module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command for azure Ad sync provisioning error isn't currently available.They are all managed and can be seen in azure provisioning audit logs i.e; through GUI.The Only command available is through msol like the command you provided(Get-MsolDirSyncProvisioningError -ErrorCategory PropertyConflict ).

---

This may not be the requirement for script but  you may give a try with below commands for a particular user(UPN) if it can help else please ignore.

Example command:

1.

```
(Get-AzureADUser -All 1| where {$_.UserPrincipalName -like "user@xyz.OnMicrosoft.com"}).dirsyncprovisioningerrors | fl
```

(or)

```
( get-azureaduser -all $true -Filter "startswith(UserPrincipalName,'admin@xyz.onmicrosoft.com')").dirsyncprovisioningerrors
```

**Reference:**
[get-azureaduser-vs-get-msoluser |community.spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2234333-get-azureaduser-vs-get-msoluser)

Comment: Thanks! I supposed that command is unavailable. I've use your suggested instruction and all users that I have hasn't that attribute. I suppose it be created and filled when a user has a sync error.